# where are the helpful utility css classes/variables for angular material?

Tags: css, angular-material, material-design, angular-material2, theming

I am relatively new to using angular material and it has taken a bit more work to use than I have faced using some other css frameworks like PrimeNG, Fomantic/Semantic UI. Most recently I have used PrimeNG which optionally comes with its own suite of utility classes in the form of the primeflex package. It does not appear that material has this (due to them leaving it up to you to decide i suppose) and I am therefore opting to use primeflex WITH angular material components. Is there an existing suite of material css classes that i can use instead, like simple classes that just give flex styles, height: 100%, etc.

My other problem is that I would like to tap into material in order to give my components background/font color styling relative to the current theme but I have not been able to find a 'helper class' that applies the current primary/accent/warn color to an element given the current theme. Any references to documentation are highly appreciated.

I assumed it would look something similar to:

```
// my-theme.css

@use '@angular/material' as mat;

.my-primary-text-class {
  color: mat.$primary-text-color
}
```

or something similar?

Comment: https://material.angular.io/guide/typography  You're correct about how it would work when it comes to custom stuff, as well as for exporting whatever material themes you're using. when it comes to individual components, you can add to that angular-components css to influence any material components used. so if you have a ```toolbar``` component in angular with a mat-row component used, you can add the following to the toolbars css: ```.mat-row:hover {background-color: some-color; }```

Comment: yes but i am trying to add colors in a way that will still work with material if i add the option to change the theme to the user. If i hard code a color to a component and then change the theme that component will still be the color i told it to be, which most likely will look out of place with the new dark/light theme selected. Seems like there would be a way material has exposed a variable for "current primary color" that they are changing when the theme changes?

Comment: i have not read this typography page yet so it will be very helpful in quickly applying changes to all the h4s (for example) once i can get this class going. Im just wondering why doesn't material provide a 'mat-bg-primary'-like class that gives a background color to a component that IS the current primary color of the selected theme

Comment: Maybe you want [themeing](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)?

Comment: I have decided to integrate tailwind into my project since they allow for helpful css utility classes and defining color themes in a way that makes adding something like: text-black-500 easily change based on theme defined